# The workspace named "Runner" does not contain a scheme named "Runner". error for Flutter integration test with patrol in iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, testing, flutter-patrol

I try to implement integration tests in my flutter project. I found [Patrol](https://patrol.leancode.co/native/overview) meet my requirement and it can assess native feature like `openNotifications` `disableWifi` etc.

I followed the tutorial on how to integrate Patrol Native code to enable this feature in iOS but I get stuck in this error. I don't know how to solve this issue because I have zero knowledge in iOS. [xcodebuild: error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWj0v.png)

My apps have 3 flavor for each env. and I run patrol test using this command.
`patrol test --target integration_test/auth/google_sign_in_test.dart --flavor development --verbose`

but i keep stop on this error for iOS.

```
 2023-03-13 08:45:40.141 xcodebuild[18956:5655849] Writing error result bundle to /var/folders/xk/rpw6m91n5vdfjl_n16_ccyg80000gn/T/ResultBundle_2023-13-03_08-45-0040.xcresult
        xcodebuild: error: The workspace named "Runner" does not contain a scheme named "Runner". The "-list" option can be used to find the names of the schemes in the workspace.
✗ Failed to build app with entrypoint google_sign_in_test.dart for iOS simulator (xcodebuild exited with code 65) (86.3s)
Error: xcodebuild exited with code 65
#0      throwToolExit (package:patrol_cli/src/base/exceptions.dart:7:3)
#1      IOSTestBackend.build.<anonymous closure> (package:patrol_cli/src/ios/ios_test_backend.dart:90:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      DisposeScope.run (package:dispose_scope/src/dispose_scope.dart:44:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      IOSTestBackend.build (package:patrol_cli/src/ios/ios_test_backend.dart:40:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      TestCommand._builderFor.<anonymous closure> (package:patrol_cli/src/commands/test.dart:227:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      _NativeTestRunner.run.runTestsOnDevice (package:patrol_cli/src/test_runner.dart:230:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:522:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      _NativeTestRunner.run (package:patrol_cli/src/test_runner.dart:258:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      TestCommand.run (package:patrol_cli/src/commands/test.dart:188:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     PatrolCommandRunner.runCommand (package:patrol_cli/src/runner/patrol_command_runner.dart:304:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     PatrolCommandRunner.run (package:patrol_cli/src/runner/patrol_command_runner.dart:243:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     patrolCommandRunner (package:patrol_cli/src/runner/patrol_command_runner.dart:47:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     main (file:///Users/bajochero/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/patrol_cli-1.0.10/bin/main.dart:6:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

This should be fixed in [patrol_cli v1.1.0](https://pub.dev/packages/patrol_cli/changelog#110).

**Old answer**

Try specifying the Build Configuration and Scheme explicitly:

```
patrol test --target integration_test/auth/google_sign_in_test.dart --flavor development --configuration Debug-development --scheme development --verbose
```